# Nginx cannot serve backend's static files

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

`Nginx` is set up with both `frontend` and `backend` services in `Docker` - both are working without any issues apart from `backend` **static files** which are not being served by `nginx` (http://api.example.com/static/...). Since frontend is SPA and consists of static files already - they have no issues being served from within `nginx` container. However, `nginx` is not serving `backend` **static files**. The static files are definitely in the nginx container (`/home/app/web/static/`) - however nginx is giving the following error when checked in the console - this is probably because the CSS file below would return **404** (which is html page) - hence it cannot apply html to CSS . Nginx log files are clear.

> Refused to apply style from
>   http://api.example.com/static/admin/css/responsive.css because its
>   MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and
>   strict MIME checking is enabled.

P.S. Backend framework is `Django` whereas Frontend is `Vue`.

**nginx.conf file**

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;

  # frontend
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
  }
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name api.example.com;

  # backend
  location ~ ^/(admin|api) {
      proxy_pass http://api;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }

  # backend static files (django)
  location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/app/web/static/;       
  }  
}
```

Comment: Is using `root /home/app/web/` instead of `alias /home/app/web/static/` gives the same result?

Comment: @Owl - same thing unfortunately

Comment: I can see that the URI is `/static/admin/css/responsive.css`, but what is the exact pathname of the file?

Comment: For that file - /home/app/web/static/admin/css/responsive.css